# hide radio button in the razor engine

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I want to hide a radiobutton. I try it like this:

```
  @if (GetBoolean("bdCanOrderOnAccount"))
                                            {
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <input type="radio" value="PAY1" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY1")) { <text> checked="checked" </text>           }>
                                                    <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY1a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodebankaccount", "Betaal op rekening")</label>
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        <!--<div class="control-group">
                                            <input type="radio" value="PAY2" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY2a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY2")) { <text> checked="checked" </text>          }>
                                            <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY2a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodeideal", "Betaal online via iDeal")</label>
                                        </div>-->


                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <input type="radio" value="PAY3" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY3")) { <text> checked="checked" </text>           }>
                                            <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodepickup", "Betaal bij afhalen")</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        <script>
                                            $(function () {                                                 
                                              var rbtn = document.getElementById('EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a');
                                              document.getElementById('EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a').style.visibility = 'hidden';

                                              });
                                            </script>
```

So if I do a alert('hoi') in the script then I see the hoi message. But the radio button is not hidden.

How can that be?

Thank you

But if I do it like this:

```
<div class="hallo">
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <input type="radio" value="PAY3" id="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" name="EcomCartPaymethodID" class="pull-left" @if (GetString("Ecom:Order.PaymentMethodID").Equals("PAY3")) { <text> checked="hecked" </text>           }>
                                            <label for="EcomCartPaymethodID_PAY3a" class="pull-left radio-label">@Translate("choosepaymentmethodepickup", "betaal bij afhalen")</label>
                                        </div>
                              </div>
```

and this:

```
<script>
                                            $(function () {                                              
                                              document.document.getElementsByClassName('hallo').style.visibility = 'hidden';

                                              });
                                            </script>
```

it doesnt hide

Comment: I ran this code myself and it hides the radio button successfully. It doesn't hide the label next to it though. Maybe you need to hide both? Or hide the entire div that encloses them?

Comment: I update the post

Comment: 1) `document.document` is wrong. 2) getElementsByClassName returns an array, so you have to set the style on the first array index (or all of them, if you expect several results).  Have you not checked your browser console for errors before just saying "it doesn't work"? That should be the very first thing you do whenever you have a problem with javascript :-) I guarantee in this case there will be a console error which you could have used to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 document.document.getElementsByClassName('hallo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

the correct syntax should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hallo')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Firstly, `document.document` makes no sense. I'll assume that's a typo.

Secondly, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of matched elements, so you have to set the style on the individual elements which are held in the array indexes, not on the array itself. For this example I've set it on the first element (`[0]`) assuming you're only expecting one result, but if you might have multiple results you'll need to loop through the array and make the assignment on all of them.